# iOS/iPhone Get FrameBuffer from GLKViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

How do I get the FrameBuffer or RenderBuffer from a 'GLKViewController' on iOS/iPhone so I can pass it to 'glBindFramebuffer' ??

I'm trying to render to a RenderTarget and then switch back to the main BackBuffer to present other information.

On all other platforms "Windows, OSX, Linux and Android" setting 'glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);' to '0' causes the system to set the default FrameBuffer.  Why is this different on iOS ?

Also I notice 'GLKView' has the 'bindDrawable' method, which is basically 'glBindFramebuffer'... Where is this method in 'GLKViewController' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awww dur, I just get the 'GLKView' from 'GLKViewController.View' and call 'bindDrawable' from there.